# How to convert multi-index columns to single index-column for pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a multi-index dataframe columns that I have retrieved from Yahoo Finance and would like to convert it to a single-index columns table. Instead of having each symbol (SPY,AMZN) correspond to the attributes (high, low, close), I would need to have an extra column with symbol name. The new symbol column would have repeated symbol name as it shows the high/low/close for each trading date.

Below is a sample output that I would like to have. 
[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhPjF.png)

Below is the multi-index dataframe that yahoo finance populate on that dataframe. 
[Multi-index dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNNoD.png)

Here is the code to retrieve data from Yahoo Finance.

```
#Import libraries
from pandas_datareader import data 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tickers = ['SPY','APPL','GOOGL'] 
start_date = '2020-01-01'
end_date = '2020-12-31'
panel_data = data.DataReader(tickers,'yahoo', start_date, end_date)

relv_data = panel_data[['High','Low','Close']]

#Inspect first 5 columns of pandas dataframe
print(relv_data.head())

#Display columns attributes
print(relv_data.columns)
```

Hope someone who is an expert with pandas dataframe could help me with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to split each index and [`droplevel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) for remove ticker labels

```py
for name, data in relv_data.groupby(level=1, axis=1):
    print(f"----------{name}----------")
    data.columns = data.columns.droplevel(1)
    print(data)
```

you can [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html) their:

```py
tickers_data = []
for ticker, data in relv_data.groupby(level=1, axis=1):
    data.columns = data.columns.droplevel(1)
    data = data.reset_index()
    data.insert(0, 'ticker', ticker)
    tickers_data.append(data)

result = pd.concat(tickers_data)
```